# I can't fix scroll view constraints in this complex view

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, constraints

I am having issues in my code with constraints. I'm seeing the following types of errors:

> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
> <NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000ea6440 UIView:0x7fc684509760.height == UIScrollView:0x7fc685818000.height   (active)>

> Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
> The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.

I think the constraints are the problem.

Another problem that I have is with the buttons in buttonview. They are offset a little bit and sometimes when the numN is changing it doesn't fit well on the screen.

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class PianoRollView: UIView {
    var numN = 127
    var numT = 4
    
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
        
        // Draw the  grid
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        context?.setStrokeColor(UIColor.black.cgColor)
        context?.setLineWidth(1.0)
        
        let noteHeight = rect.height / CGFloat(numN)
      
        for i in 1..<numN {
            let y = CGFloat(i) * noteHeight
            context?.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: y))
            context?.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width, y: y))
        }
        
        let timeSlotWidth = rect.width / CGFloat(numT)
        
        for i in 1..<numT {
            let x = CGFloat(i) * timeSlotWidth
            context?.move(to: CGPoint(x: x, y: 0))
            context?.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: x, y: rect.height))
        }
        
        // Add line to right of grid
       context?.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width, y: 0))
      context?.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width, y: rect.height))
        // Add line to left of grid
        context?.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
       context?.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: rect.height))
        
        
        // Add line to top of grid
        context?.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
       context?.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width, y: 0))
        
        // Draw bottom line
        context?.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: rect.height))
       context?.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width, y: rect.height))
        
        context?.strokePath()
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    let scrollView = UIScrollView()
    let pianoRollView = PianoRollView()
    
    // Create a container view to hold both the PianoRollView and the ButtonView
    let containerView = UIView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // Add the UIScrollView to the view controller's view
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        // Set the container view as the content view of the scroll view
        scrollView.addSubview(containerView)
        
        // Disable the autoresizing mask for both the UIScrollView and the PianoRollView
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        pianoRollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        // Set the constraints for the UIScrollView to fill the view controller's view
        scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        
        // Initialize the piano roll view
        pianoRollView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 2000, height: 2000)
        pianoRollView.layer.zPosition = 1
        
       containerView.frame = pianoRollView.frame
       
        containerView.addSubview(pianoRollView)
       
        
        // Set the constraints for the PianoRollView to fill the container view
        pianoRollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        pianoRollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        pianoRollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        pianoRollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        pianoRollView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        
        // Set the constraints for the container view to fill the scroll view
        containerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        containerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        containerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        containerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        containerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        containerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.heightAnchor).isActive = true
        
        // Add a UIView under the PianoRollView
        let buttonView = UIView()
              buttonView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        buttonView.frame =  pianoRollView.frame
        containerView.addSubview(buttonView)
        
        // Set the constraints for the ButtonView to align with the PianoRollView
        buttonView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        buttonView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        buttonView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        buttonView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        buttonView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.heightAnchor).isActive = true
        
// calculate size of notes
        let noteHeight = Int(round(pianoRollView.frame.height / CGFloat(pianoRollView.numN)) )
        
        // Add buttons to the buttonView with the same height as the space between the grids
        for i in 0..<pianoRollView.numN {
            let button = UIButton()
            button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            buttonView.addSubview(button)
            
            button.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: buttonView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
            button.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: buttonView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
            button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: buttonView.topAnchor, constant: CGFloat(i) * CGFloat(noteHeight)).isActive = true
            button.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: buttonView.topAnchor, constant: CGFloat(i+1) * CGFloat(noteHeight)).isActive = true

            button.setTitle("Button \(i)", for: .normal)
            button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
            button.backgroundColor = .red
        }

        // Set the content size of the scroll view to match the size of the piano roll view
        scrollView.contentSize = containerView.bounds.size
        
        // Enable scrolling in both directions
        scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
        scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = true
        scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = true
        
        // Set the background color of the piano roll view to white
        pianoRollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

     
        // Set the delegate of the scroll view to self
        scrollView.delegate = self
        
        // Set the minimum zoom scale
       let minZoomScale = max(view.bounds.width / pianoRollView.bounds.width, view.bounds.height / pianoRollView.bounds.height)
       scrollView.minimumZoomScale = minZoomScale
       // scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1
        scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 5
    }
    
    // Return the container view in the viewForZooming method
    func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return containerView
    }
    func scrollViewDidZoom(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        // Adjust the content offset so that the content stays centered when zooming
        let horizontalInset = max(0, (scrollView.bounds.width - scrollView.contentSize.width) / 2)
        let verticalInset = max(0, (scrollView.bounds.height - scrollView.contentSize.height) / 2)
        scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: verticalInset, left: horizontalInset, bottom: verticalInset, right: horizontalInset)
    }
}
```

Comment: You're doing a few odd things... and it's not clear what you're trying to get. You have this line: `pianoRollView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 2000, height: 2000)` ... Do you want a `2000x2000 pianoRollView` that you can scroll around?

Comment: Is this your goal? https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCL0G.png

Comment: Please focus on one issue per question.

Comment: @DonMag my brother you are the man, thats what Iam looking for, please tell me how to do it,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the problem is that you're mixing explicit frame settings with constraints.

As a rule when working with `UIScrollView`, we either set frames and `.contentSize` ***OR*** we use constraints and let auto-layout do all the work for us.

It can be very helpful to organize your code into "related" tasks. For example:

- create views and set properties
- add all views to the hierarchy
- set constraints
- do any additional tasks

With your project, `scrollView` / `pianoRollView` / `containerView` are created as class properties, so the first thing in `viewDidLoad()` will be:

```
    // buttons will go under the PianoRollView
    let buttonView = UIView()
```

next, add them to the view hierarchy:

```
    // Add the UIScrollView to the view controller's view
    view.addSubview(scrollView)

    // Set the container view as the content view of the scroll view
    scrollView.addSubview(containerView)

    // add buttonView to containerView
    containerView.addSubview(buttonView)

    // add pianoRollView to containerView
    containerView.addSubview(pianoRollView)
```

we want to use auto-layout, so follow that with:

```
    // we will use auto-layout on all views
    scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    buttonView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    pianoRollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

Now we can set constraints on all those views, relative to each other...

```
    // we (almost) always want to respect the safe area
    let safeG = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide

    // we want to constrain scrollView subviews to the scrollView's Content Layout Guide
    let contentG = scrollView.contentLayoutGuide
    
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        
        // Set the constraints for the UIScrollView to fill the view controller's view (safe area)
        scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeG.leadingAnchor),
        scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeG.trailingAnchor),
        scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeG.topAnchor),
        scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeG.bottomAnchor),

        // constrain containerView to Content Layout Guide
        //  this will define the "scrollable area"
        //  so we won't be setting .contentSize anywhere
        containerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentG.leadingAnchor),
        containerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentG.trailingAnchor),
        containerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentG.topAnchor),
        containerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentG.bottomAnchor),
        
        // constrain all 4 sides of buttonView to containerView
        buttonView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor),
        buttonView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor),
        buttonView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor),
        buttonView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor),
        
        // constrain all 4 sides of pianoRollView to containerView
        pianoRollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor),
        pianoRollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor),
        pianoRollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor),
        pianoRollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor),
        
        // pianoRollView width
        pianoRollView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 2000.0),
        
    ])
```

Note that we do **NOT** set a `heightAnchor` on `pianoRollView`. You'll see why...

You're also adding `numN` buttons to `buttonView` ... that makes a little more sense to do *after* setting constraints on the above views.

Your code indicates you want pianoView (and thus, buttonView) to have a Height of 2000. And then you want to evenly fill that height with `numN` buttons.

In the code you posted, you're calculating the buttons' height like this:

```
let noteHeight = Int(round(pianoRollView.frame.height / CGFloat(pianoRollView.numN)) )
```

So, Height is 2000 and numN is 127:

```
2000.0 / 127.0 == 15.748031496062993
```

You're using `round()`, which is fine because it's a good idea to NOT use partial-points.

If we use `round()`, we get:

```
round(2000.0 / 127.0) == 16.0
```

but, if we have 127 buttons each with a Height of 16...

```
16 * 127 == 2032
```

So we won't see the bottom two buttons!

We could try using `floor()` ... and we get:

```
floor(2000.0 / 127.0) == 15
```

but, if we have 127 buttons each with a Height of 15...

```
15 * 127 == 1905
```

So we have a 95-point "gap" at the bottom!

What you probably want to do is use `floor()` and `ceil()`, and then compare those values to see which one is *closest to* 2000.

This could be written in fewer lines, but for clarification:

```
// in this example, pianoRollView.numN is 127
let targetHeight: CGFloat = 2000.0
let floatNumN: CGFloat = CGFloat(pianoRollView.numN)

let noteH1: CGFloat = floor(targetHeight / floatNumN)   // == 15.0
let noteH2: CGFloat = ceil(targetHeight / floatNumN)    // == 16.0

let totalHeight1: CGFloat = noteH1 * floatNumN          // == 1905
let totalHeight2: CGFloat = noteH2 * floatNumN          // == 2032
    
let diff1: CGFloat = abs(targetHeight - totalHeight1)   // == 95
let diff2: CGFloat = abs(targetHeight - totalHeight2)   // == 32

// if diff1 is less than diff2, use noteH1 else noteH2
let noteHeight: CGFloat = diff1 < diff2 ? noteH1 : noteH2
```

`noteHeight` now equals `16` and the `totalHeight` equals `2032` ... which is *about* 2000.

Instead of setting a height on `buttonView` and then looping through and setting frames of the buttons, let's continue to take advantage of auto-layout.

We'll create a "vertical chain" of constraints:

- constrain the Top of the *first* button to the Top of `buttonView`
- constrain the Top of each following button to the Bottom of the button above it
- constrain the Bottom of the *last* button to the Bottom of `buttonView`

that constraint chain now:

- determines the height of buttonView
- which also determines the height of pianoRollView
- which also determines the height of containerView
- which defines the .contentSize -- the "scrollable area"

Another issue you have is that you are using different calculations for `noteHeight` for your buttons:

```
let noteHeight = Int(round(pianoRollView.frame.height / CGFloat(pianoRollView.numN)) )
```

and for the horizontal lines in `pianoRollView`:

```
let noteHeight = rect.height / CGFloat(numN)
```

So your buttons each had a height of `16-points`, but your lines were spaced at `15.748031496062993`.

A better option would be to make `noteHeight` a **property of `pianoRollView`** ... and set it when you've calculated `noteHeight` (the button height) in `viewDidLoad()`. No need for another calculation.

Here's the full thing, with some additional modifications. Read through the comments so you understand what's going on:

```
class PianoRollView: UIView {
    
    var noteHeight: CGFloat = 0
    
    var numN = 127
    var numT = 4
    
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
        
        // Draw the  grid
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        context?.setStrokeColor(UIColor.black.cgColor)
        context?.setLineWidth(1.0)
        
        // UIKit *may* tell us to draw only PART of the view
        //  (the rect), so use bounds instead of rect
        
        // noteHeight will be set by the controller
        //  when it calculates the button heights
        // let noteHeight = rect.height / CGFloat(numN)

        for i in 1..<numN {
            let y = CGFloat(i) * noteHeight
            context?.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: y))
            context?.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.width, y: y))
        }
        
        let timeSlotWidth = bounds.width / CGFloat(numT)
        
        for i in 1..<numT {
            let x = CGFloat(i) * timeSlotWidth
            context?.move(to: CGPoint(x: x, y: 0))
            context?.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: x, y: bounds.height))
        }
        
        // Add line to right of grid
        context?.move(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.width, y: 0))
        context?.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.width, y: bounds.height))
        // Add line to left of grid
        context?.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
        context?.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: bounds.height))
        
        
        // Add line to top of grid
        context?.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
        context?.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.width, y: 0))
        
        // Draw bottom line
        context?.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: bounds.height))
        context?.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.width, y: bounds.height))
        
        context?.strokePath()
        
    }
    
}

class PianoViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    
    let scrollView = UIScrollView()
    let pianoRollView = PianoRollView()
    
    // Create a container view to hold both the PianoRollView and the ButtonView
    let containerView = UIView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.95, alpha: 1.0)

        // buttons will go under the PianoRollView
        let buttonView = UIView()

        // Add the UIScrollView to the view controller's view
        view.addSubview(scrollView)

        // Set the container view as the content view of the scroll view
        scrollView.addSubview(containerView)

        // add buttonView to containerView
        containerView.addSubview(buttonView)

        // add pianoRollView to containerView
        containerView.addSubview(pianoRollView)

        // we will use auto-layout on all views
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        buttonView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        pianoRollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        // we (almost) always want to respect the safe area
        let safeG = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        // we want to constrain scrollView subviews to the scrollView's Content Layout Guide
        let contentG = scrollView.contentLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            // Set the constraints for the UIScrollView to fill the view controller's view (safe area)
            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeG.leadingAnchor),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeG.trailingAnchor),
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeG.topAnchor),
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeG.bottomAnchor),

            // constrain containerView to Content Layout Guide
            //  this will define the "scrollable area"
            //  so we won't be setting .contentSize anywhere
            containerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentG.leadingAnchor),
            containerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentG.trailingAnchor),
            containerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentG.topAnchor),
            containerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentG.bottomAnchor),
            
            // constrain all 4 sides of buttonView to containerView
            buttonView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor),
            buttonView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor),
            buttonView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor),
            buttonView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor),
            
            // constrain all 4 sides of pianoRollView to containerView
            pianoRollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor),
            pianoRollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor),
            pianoRollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor),
            pianoRollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor),
            
            // pianoRollView width
            pianoRollView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 2000.0),
            // we don't set height, because that will be controlled by the
            //  number of buttons (pianoRollView.numN) sized to get
            //  as close to 2000 as possible
            //pianoRollView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 2000.0),
            
        ])

        // calculate size of notes
        
        // let's get close to 2000

        // in this example, pianoRollView.numN is 127
        let targetHeight: CGFloat = 2000.0
        let floatNumN: CGFloat = CGFloat(pianoRollView.numN)

        let noteH1: CGFloat = floor(targetHeight / floatNumN)   // == 15.0
        let noteH2: CGFloat = ceil(targetHeight / floatNumN)    // == 16.0

        let totalHeight1: CGFloat = noteH1 * floatNumN          // == 1905
        let totalHeight2: CGFloat = noteH2 * floatNumN          // == 2032
        
        let diff1: CGFloat = abs(targetHeight - totalHeight1)   // == 95
        let diff2: CGFloat = abs(targetHeight - totalHeight2)   // == 32

        // if diff1 is less than diff2, use noteH1 else noteH2
        let noteHeight: CGFloat = diff1 < diff2 ? noteH1 : noteH2

        // noteHeight now equals 16
        
        // Add buttons to the buttonView
        //  we can constrain them vertically to each other
        var previousButton: UIButton!
        for i in 0..<pianoRollView.numN {
            let button = UIButton()
            button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            buttonView.addSubview(button)
            
            button.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: buttonView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
            button.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: buttonView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
            button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: noteHeight).isActive = true
            
            if previousButton == nil {
                // constrain FIRST button to Top of buttonView
                button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: buttonView.topAnchor).isActive = true
            } else {
                // constrain other buttons to Bottom of Previous Button
                button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: previousButton.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
            }
            
            // update previousButton to the current button
            previousButton = button
            
            button.setTitle("Button \(i)", for: .normal)
            button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
            button.backgroundColor = .red
        }
        
        // constrain bottom of LAST button to bottom of buttonsView
        previousButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: buttonView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        
        // so, our buttons are constrained with a "vertical chain" inside buttonView
        //  which determines the height of buttonView
        //  which also determines the height of pianoRollView
        //  which also determines the height of containerView
        //  which defines the .contentSize -- the "scrollable area"
        
        // set the noteHeight in pianoRollView so it will match
        //  pianoRollView no longer needs to re-caluclate the "line spacing"
        pianoRollView.noteHeight = noteHeight
        
        // these all default to True, so not needed
        // Enable scrolling in both directions
        //scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
        //scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = true
        //scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = true
        
        // Set the background color of the piano roll view to clear
        pianoRollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        
        // Set the delegate of the scroll view to self
        scrollView.delegate = self
        
        // Set the minimum zoom scale
        // can't do this here... views have not been laid-out yet
        //  so do it in viewDidAppear
        //let minZoomScale = max(view.bounds.width / pianoRollView.bounds.width, view.bounds.height / pianoRollView.bounds.height)
        //scrollView.minimumZoomScale = minZoomScale
        
        scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 5
        
        // during development, so we can see the scrollView framing
        scrollView.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        
    }
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        // views have been laid-out, so now we can use their frames/bounds to calculate minZoomScale
        let minZoomScale = min(scrollView.frame.width / pianoRollView.bounds.width, scrollView.frame.height / pianoRollView.bounds.height)
        scrollView.minimumZoomScale = minZoomScale
    }
    
    // Return the container view in the viewForZooming method
    func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return containerView
    }
    func scrollViewDidZoom(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        // Adjust the content offset so that the content stays centered when zooming
        let horizontalInset = max(0, (scrollView.frame.width - scrollView.contentSize.width) / 2)
        let verticalInset = max(0, (scrollView.frame.height - scrollView.contentSize.height) / 2)
        scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: verticalInset, left: horizontalInset, bottom: verticalInset, right: horizontalInset)
    }
}
```

If any of that is not clear - or even if you now understand it all - you would really benefit yourself by working through a bunch of Auto-Layout / `UIScrollView` tutorials...

---

**Edit**

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    // views have been laid-out, so now we can use their frames/bounds to calculate minZoomScale

    // if we want min zoom to fit
    //  FULL pianoRollView
    let minZoomScale = min(scrollView.frame.width / pianoRollView.bounds.width, scrollView.frame.height / pianoRollView.bounds.height)
    
    // if we want min zoom to fit
    //  pianoRollView HEIGHT
    //let minZoomScale = scrollView.frame.height / pianoRollView.bounds.height
    
    // if we want min zoom to fit
    //  one "column" of pianoRollView
    //let minZoomScale = scrollView.frame.width / (pianoRollView.bounds.width / CGFloat(pianoRollView.numT))
    
    scrollView.minimumZoomScale = minZoomScale
}
```

Comment: thank you so much ,it work ,but I didn't get the holl thing about scroll view everywhere I see people set content size and constrain ,another thing how can I set zoom to just zoom out enough to just see one side of the pianoroll  fits screen which would be vertical one because I would to sent piano size each time differently and the horizontal side is mostly bigger than vertical

Comment: @user8058965 - not sure what you mean by *"just see one side of the pianoroll"* ... check the **Edit** to my answer and see if that's what you need. *"everywhere I see people set content size and constrain"* ... as I mentioned, you would really benefit yourself by working through a bunch of Auto-Layout / UIScrollView tutorials...

Comment: thank you so much,i am trying to find good tutorial on auto layout and scrollview but I don't find something use full ,do you have any recommendation ,you know I add another scrollview to the left side and repeat the same thing on the left side scrollview and sync both it work fine, the only problem I have,when I zoom out I can see the background left scrollview,i think its a constrain problem again, i like to show it to you,i am sure you can help me,i like how you teach, do you have any idea how to show you the code, should I ask a new question,or something else ,please help

Comment: @user8058965 - head over to Google (or your favorite search engine) and search for `ios autolayout tutorial` -- then work through about a dozen of them. And I mean **work through** - not just scan read them. As far as what else you're trying to do - adding another scroll view and syncing them - if you put together a [mre] and post it somewhere like GitHub I can take a quick look at it.

Comment: thank you for your fast response,for me to make minimal reproducible examples is a quite journey,i try my best to make it work, but I wish I could send it like this question because its not much to it than what you see in this post,

Comment: @user8058965 - post the code to pastebin if it is not much more than what's posted here.

Comment: dude you are the man , god bless you and your family, this is a pastebin link,  https://pastebin.com/M7XRzc1D

Comment: @user8058965 - not sure what your ultimate goal is, but  this may help: https://pastebin.com/hW7xnYw1 ... see the notes at the top and comments in the code

Comment: thank you so much ,it work like a champ, dude you even make it look good , :) speechless ,

Comment: dude I have again problem in my project, can I give you a pastebin again,i have nobody to show it, and online ,with my English and so many problem in my code, I don't think anyone could help, please if its possible for you

Comment: @user8058965 - if you post something, I will try to take a look at it.

Comment: dude you are the man. I don't know how to thank you.  https://pastebin.com/kTnCNHTM

Comment: i Lust my hope,I believe it will be no answer to my post,sorry for my dumb questions, I’m not a programmer at all.I am music producer and  try to make my app.thanks anyway

Comment: @user8058965 - sorry... I took a look at it, but that is WAY too much for "a little help." You need to break that down into small, individual tasks and work on learning one thing at a time. Or... you need to hire someone.

Comment: my brother i thought thats small task for a programmer,:)hahah,you are right I asked to much, but I find the 2,3 question,now I need the first one, even asked a new question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75894754/how-to-pan-after-the-pan-gesture-moves-certain-amounts ,but the pastebin is more complete than this question , I really like to hire someone ,but I barely can pay my livings, i have to make it by my self ,anyway,god bless you my brother ,you already helped me more than what I asked,