# how to pan after the pan gesture moves certain amounts

Tags: ios, swift, uipangesturerecognizer

I need help ,I made a view that I divided with lines and when I touch it make a rect between the lines, like this image,[image]

and I made a pan gesture to move the rects that I draw, between the lines, it works but thats not what I want ,when I move my finger little bit it moves and thats the problems, even when I move just the y it recognise the smallest amount of x and move both, I need to move my rect after the pan is more than the divisions then move the rect ,i want when I select my rect and move my finger to the division upper or lower or left or right one from the existing one that I'm in then move.
so I came up with this but it doesn't work the right way, the height of the division is noteheight and the width between them is timeSlotWidtho ,

```
@objc func handlePanGesture(_ gestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    
    let touchLocation = gestureRecognizer.location(in: self)
    let location = touchLocation
    let timeSlotWidtho = bounds.width / CGFloat(numT)
    let note = CGFloat(numN) - location.y / noteHeight
    let startTime = Double(Int(location.x / timeSlotWidtho))
    let duration = Double(numT) / Double(numT)
    let noteHeight = bounds.height / CGFloat(numN)  
  
     var lastPanY: CGFloat = 0
     var lastPanx: CGFloat = 0

    switch gestureRecognizer.state {
        
    case .began:
        // Check if the user has touched a note rectangle
        
        // Check if a note with the same parameters already exists
        for (index, existingNote) in notes.enumerated() {
            if existingNote.note == Int(note) && existingNote.startTime == startTime && existingNote.duration == duration {
                lastPanY = location.y
                lastPanx = location.x
                selectedNoteIndex = index
                setNeedsDisplay()
                
            }
        }
        
    case .changed:
        // Move the selected note rectangle
        let translation = gestureRecognizer.translation(in: self)
        
     
        
        // Check if a note with the same parameters already exists
        for (index, existingNote) in notes.enumerated() {
            if existingNote.note == Int(note) && existingNote.startTime == startTime && existingNote.duration == duration {
                
                let deltaY = lastPanY - translation.y
                let deltax = lastPanx - translation.x
                
                
                if abs(deltaY) > noteHeight  {
                   
                    let direction = deltaY > lastPanY ? 1 : -1
                    let newValue =  existingNote.note + direction
                    if newValue >= 0 && newValue <= numN - 1 {
                        notes[index].note = newValue
                        // do something with intValue
                        lastPanY = translation.y
                        
                     
                        
                    
                        selectedNoteIndex = index
                        setNeedsDisplay()
                       
                    }
                    
                }
                if abs(deltax) > timeSlotWidtho  {
                 
                 let directionl = deltax < lastPanx ? 1.0 : -1.0
                 let newValuel =  existingNote.startTime + directionl
                 if newValuel >= 0 && Int(newValuel) <= numT  {
                 notes[index].startTime = newValuel
                 // do something with intValue
                 lastPanx = translation.x
                 
             
                 selectedNoteIndex = index
                 setNeedsDisplay()
                 
                 }
                 }
                
                selectedNoteIndex = index
                setNeedsDisplay()
               
            }
        }
        
        
        
    case .ended:
        // the end
        setNeedsDisplay()
    default:
        print("wef")
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: Basically don't look at the distance at all. Don't follow the finger. Just look at what square the finger is actually in right now. If the note isn't in that square, and that square is empty, move it there. Otherwise do nothing.

Comment: Thank you for your response , good idea,I did something like that after reading your comment ,if you look the code,I defined let note = CGFloat(numN) - location.y / noteHeight,so i defined new variable that is the location + translation,that makes where I am after pan,so made new note ,instead of location is this value,work fine,until I make the division much smaller,in the foto is 12/16,when I make it 127/32,is so small and my rect is so small,and doesn’t work,i can select the rect,but doesn’t move,I don’t know if the touch location can’t be so small or I defined the note not right,,

Comment: because when is big,also I need to grab the edge of the rect,to work,do you have any idea,and another problem,when I pan outside the note,I mean i didn’t select the note,and I pan and I reach to a note it will move,I don’t want that,I want only if I select the note first and pan then move,but now even if the not is not selected and I pan and reach the note it will be selected and move ,

Comment: The note needs to be a view and it needs to be the thing that has the pan gesture recognizer on it. That way only the note can be dragged; a gesture that starts outside the note won't be affected. Then, as I said before, in the code that responds to the drag, convert the coordinate system to "look at" the whole grid and figure out which square you are in in the grid, and reposition the note there if and only if that square has changed. This really is very easy, don't overthink it. Drop all your "translation" code, none of that matters, just look at where the finger actually is right now.

Comment: Take a look at my Diabelli's Theme app (free), what I'm doing is actually more complex than you even need, but look at it anyway: you can drag a square from the grid onto any other square and then drop it there. This swaps it with the square that was there already, you don't need that part. And I'm actually permitting the square to be physically dragged and highlighting the square you _would_ drop into if you let go now, you seem not to want that either. But what you do want is awareness of what square the finger is now over, just like what I'm doing.

Comment: Do you mean ,that each note should be a view instead of a cgrect? Another thing,how should I look at the whole grid,how to know wher is my finger? Is there any open source code for your app, Diabelli's Theme app?i would like to study your code.

Comment: A view is a drawing plus touch. Touch is exactly what you need. You want to drag a drawing; that's a view. As for the grid: It's just basic arithmetic.

Comment: Dude I don’t understand what you trying to say,it would be cool to see an example,you know I am trying to make pianoroll,look at GarageBand pianoroll you will understand what I want,I may have 100 notes in the screen which I get in an array,for each of them making a view ,it would be pain ,and the constraints,and I use the touch to create the notes ,to put notes on grid,other thing,I don’t want to move freely like your app,I need to be snapped to grid,and move one step at time,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is what you're describing:

[image]

(At the end of the "video", I am demonstrating that starting a drag outside of the note does not affect the note.)

If that is what you are after, just follow the instructions I already gave you in the comments. Make each note a view with a pan gesture recognizer. In that recognizer's target method's `.changed` state, look simply at the location of the first touch in your grid view and calculate the top left point of the grid rectangle that that touch is in. If the note's origin is not at that point, make it so.

Here's my pan gesture recognizer target method. It assumes that, as I've just said, each note is a view with its own pan gesture recognizer. It also assumes we have a grid view called `grid` that knows how to report where the top left corners of its rectangles are, and that the note is a subview of the grid view:

```
@objc func dragged(_ g: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    guard let note = g.view else { return }
    if g.state == .changed {
        let pt = g.location(ofTouch: 0, in: grid)
        let targetOrigin = grid.divisionOriginFor(point: pt)
        let currentOrigin = note.frame.origin
        if currentOrigin != targetOrigin {
            var newframe = note.frame
            newframe.origin = targetOrigin
            if grid.bounds.intersection(newframe) == newframe {
                note.frame = newframe
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In that code, we assume that the grid view's `divisionOriginFor(point:)` is a method that looks at where the `point` is and decides what grid rectangle ("division") it is in and reports the top left corner of that rectangle. It might go like this (I assume that `xct` and `yct` are properties providing the number of lines/divisions for the grid):

```
func divisionOriginFor(point pt: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
    let qx = Int(pt.x) / Int(bounds.width / CGFloat(xct))
    let qy = Int(pt.y) / Int(bounds.height / CGFloat(yct))
    return CGPoint(
        x: bounds.width / CGFloat(xct) * CGFloat(qx),
        y: bounds.height / CGFloat(yct) * CGFloat(qy)
    )
}
```

Comment: bro, it work good util , I change the width of the view, if my touch is at the beginning of the view ,it works fine ,but if in the middle or end ,then it will jump to the position of my touch ,because the view is bigger than divisions , I tried so many ways but dosent work,it must move one step from where it is,indipent of the direction of touch, do you have any idea , please help if you can